# How do I center my caption in media size?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a media size that is centered in regular size, when I changed it max-width of 480 the caption is on the left.

but it is stuck to the left. How can I change the code so the caption is in the middle when in media size?

```css
caption {
   font-family: "Rock Salt", cursive;
   padding: 20px;
   font-style: italic;
   caption-side: Top;
   color: #666;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }




@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  caption {
    caption-side: Top;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
```

```html
<section id="right"> 
        <table> 
           <caption>Books everyone will enjoy!</caption> 
           <thead> 
              <th colspan="4">Recommended childrens books!</th> 
              <th colspan="2" style="display: none">Recommended childrens books!</th> 
              <tr> 
                 <th colspan="1">Front of the book</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Title of the book</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Authors</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Book Summary</th> 
             </tr> 
           </thead>
```

Comment: Please add a picture of your problem, preferably a code that can be run

Comment: It looks like this https://imgur.com/a/AQxPtl8
and im not sure wym by a code that can be run?
the code works in regular size. But when I try to run it in mobile size it stays suck in the left
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  caption {
    caption-side: Top;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

Answer (score 0):

you need to center the block element:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   caption {
      caption-side: Top;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It still looks the same, is there another place i'm supposed to fix it? width maybe?

Comment: add your html...

Comment: <section id="right">
    
        <table>
          <caption>Books everyone will enjoy!</caption>
            <thead>
                <th colspan="4">Recommended childrens books!</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="display: none">Recommended childrens books!</th>
              
              <tr>
                <th colspan="1">Front of the book</th>
                <th colspan="1">Title of the book</th>
                <th colspan="1">Authors</th>
                <th colspan="1">Book Summary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

Comment: It looks like this (im not sure why it formatted weird) but this is the part of my HTML that has the caption in it.

Answer (score 0):

just add margin:0 auto to your table

```css
caption {
   font-family: "Rock Salt", cursive;
   padding: 20px;
   font-style: italic;
   caption-side: Top;
   color: #666;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }

table{
margin:0 auto;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  caption {
    caption-side: Top;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<section id="right"> 
        <table> 
           <caption>Books everyone will enjoy!</caption> 
           <thead> 
              <th colspan="4">Recommended childrens books!</th> 
              <th colspan="2" style="display: none">Recommended childrens books!</th> 
              <tr> 
                 <th colspan="1">Front of the book</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Title of the book</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Authors</th> 
                 <th colspan="1">Book Summary</th> 
             </tr> 
           </thead>
         </table>
```

Comment: it is in the center in normal size but when I hit F12 to go into mobile size. It's still stuck on the left. I entered in the code and it did not work like it was supposed to.

Comment: this works here for all sizes.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I had to add caption to this piece
table, tbody, tr, td, th { 
  display: block; 
 }
once I added caption
caption, table, tbody, tr, td, th { 
  display: block; 
 }
it centered like I wanted it to. thank you though for your help